# Recursive embeddable schema to build up a tree

Tags: sdl-tridion, schema, embedded-items

I would like to build up a tree of components in a component as shown below. This would require an embeddable schema setup in which it would have a component link field and an embeddable schema which would link to itself. Is this possible in Tridion?

[image]

Of course alternatively I can do this by component-linking *Component AA* and *Component AB* from *Component A* and so on. In that approach these loose components themselves will have to include their children components.

But this is not what I want as I would like to define the relationship between all the Components in a single Component.

Comment: Welcome to Tridion Stack Exchange. Your question seems similar enough to actually our very first Q&A on this site. :-) Check it out and let us know if the two are close enough to note this one as a duplicate: https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-to-design-a-recursive-menu-schema

Comment: If you share more information about the problem you are trying to solve, you might get more insights into possible ways to model your functional scenario in Tridion

Answer (score 4):

If you build an embedded schema model deeper than two levels, you will find that it is nightmare to use in the gui. I sugest that you look at category and keyword navigation design pattern instead, which will let you build a tree of relationships you are looking for.

Add a metadata schema to manage any additional properties you need,

https://docs.sdl.com/783502/676687/sdl-tridion-sites-9-1/intelligent-navigation

Comment: this is actually a great idea

Answer (score 3):

There is no supported recursive schemas option in Tridion. You have to define schemas for each level and then link them.

Sorry to break your heart, but sometimes Tridion is cruel and is not kind to navigation items. A lot of us have tried different approaches and most of them are semi-hard-coded with a lot of assumptions.

Comment: You can have a schema that allows component links to components based on the same schema...https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-to-design-a-recursive-menu-schema

Comment: Yes. I should correct myself. I was talking about embedable schema referencing itself. That is not allowed.

Comment: Because he was looking for a single component solution

Comment: Note that Tridion is not as cruel as not allowing recursively nested elements at all in a Schema, but it will qualify your Schema as “complex” and as a result, you won’t be able to use the fields editor; you can only edit the raw XML in the CME. This is now deprecated. Consider other options.

Comment: You are 100% correct @MarkoMilic - I misread the "single component" part.

Comment: FYI: I believe a _standard_ GUI-friendly (or non-complex) Schema is called a "web" Schema, which coincidentally has nothing to do with "SDL Web."